# What is wrong if a dedicated SQL-Server 2005 on a win2003 Server creeps

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i have a sql-server 2005 on a win2003 32-bit (3,5GB RAM) 4 CPU Server with a RAID 5 Disk-Array which perform at 1/10 of a virtual 2008-SQL-Server Win2008 32 Bit 2GB RAM Raid 5 Server.

The Job is to delet 8,5 Mio Records out of one table of one database. After 6 hours the virtual server as a test-environment has finished the job. At the same time the productive-server has done allmost 1 Mio deletions. Whats wrong with that real win2003 server?

where to look, which parameters rule on a matter?

Peace

Ice

PS: is it unfair compairing these systems?

Comment: How many disks in the two RAID-5 arrays and what type are they? a 3 x  7.2k SATA RAID 5 would be >6x slower than a 9 x 15k SAS RAID-5 volume for this sort of task just to take an extreme example. If the VM RAID 5 volume is actually on a good SAN the difference could be even more.

Comment: The win2003/sql2005 server has a raid5 with 4 disks plus one spare. The win2008/sql2008 server has a 90GB partition defined on a raid 5 with 3 disks, no SAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the production server has other requests to serve, so it has to share resources and wait on locks.

[This suggestion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082751/how-to-delete-8-500000-records-from-one-table-on-sql-server/2082765#2082765) should solve your problem just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think the performance difference would be that bad, but it all depends.  I've benchmarked up to a 7 fold increase in application performance when changing from 03/sql05 to an 08/sql08 on the same hardware.  You might try changing the parallelism to 1 on the 905 server.  I've seen poorly hinted queries improve by doing that.  In addition check to see what ram each one has, if there is any other disk I/O activity and what processor type.  Remember that a 2.4 ghz nehalem processor can make a merom 3.2 ghz proc look like its running at half speed.

Comment: If the delete statement is poor designed doesn't matter because on both of the servers run's the same. 
Working with several sql-servers all days i think that the win03/sql05 is underperforming and on the other side i'm astonished how good the win08/sql08 is running...

Comment: locking better locking escaltion is one of hte 08 improvements.  I'm no sql wizard (so I'm not sure why) but statements that run fine on 08 seem to benefit from changing the parralellism

Answer (score 0):

Look at the execution plans for the delete statement on both machines and see how they differ; make sure the stats are updated.